# Get the copy task id in SpringCM

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm following this link to copy a document from one folder to another in springCM:
https://developers.docusign.com/clm-api/guides/task-api
at this section of the page: **Copy Document Tasks - Initiate Copy - Sample Request**

The copy is successful and I can verify that there is a new document in the destination folder, but I'm also trying to get back the object that contains the `status` and the `Href`.
But I'm getting an exception when try to desalinize the object to my custom one that matches the response.

```
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: \u001f. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

This is my code along with my custom object:

```
// my custom object
public class SCMDocumentCopyResponse
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
}

// when in initiating the request
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("{\"DocumentsToCopy\":[{\"Href\":\"https://myapi/documents/785252f4ABC\"}],\"DestinationFolder\":{\"Href\":\"https://myapi/folders/f77e277a-\XYZ"}}");
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, byteContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var final = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SCMDocumentCopyResponse>(result);
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you give me a working code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have html response from your server.
And when you try to deserialize response - you got this exception.

Try to check you response. Is json really there, as you expect.
Also, you should check response status. And try to deserialize only success response.